# Bootstrap not including any glyphicons

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bower, glyphicons, bootstrapper

First time using bootstrap. I added "bootstrap":"3.3.7" to my dependencies in my bower.json file and it adds to my wwwroot/lib folder but I know it's supposed to include a fonts folder in the bootstrap directory, but it's not there. I tried downloading the bootstrap.zip file from their website, extracting that file and then adding the fonts folder included in that download to my bootstrap directory, but it still didn't work. I've tried looking in bootstrap.css file for the @font-face for glyphicons but there are none. I am just learning how to implement everything into an ASP.Net Core app so I'm new to these technologies.

Comment: Using chrome debugger, or any browser debugger, see the network traffic and see if it is requesting the fonts and if it is able to find it. That will give you an idea.

Comment: Ok so I did this and when I inpected the element and went to Network and Fonts, there's nothing

Comment: what do you mean there is nothing? On the network tab you need to refresh your page and see if the browser sends a request to get the fonts and see what the response to that request is.

Comment: Ya sorry, wasn't really clear, it's not making any request for fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `@font-face` is defined in [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/). Also, unless you have at least one html element using the font, it will not be requested. So you need to use the font in a style rule (the @font-face doesn't count).

Therefore, download fontawesome and then add an element to your html and then the font will be requested. An element like this for example:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
```

Comment: Ok, I downloaded font-awesome and put it in my project, then I added the link to the font-awesome.css onto my .cshtml page. I originally had the same element just in an <i> tag, I changed it to span, didn't work either. Also still not making any requests for fonts

Comment: @NoahHornak and it is still not working? and can you be more specific about what is not working.

Comment: I edited my comment. It's just not making any requests for fonts still. Inside the font-awesome.css, it has a @font-face, but it doesn't contain any references to glyphicons in the document, if that helps any.

Comment: Did you put the above `span` in your page's html?

Comment: Yes I did, there is still no sign of the element on the page in my browser and there is still no request for a font when I inspect and refresh

Comment: Ugh, I feel so stupid ,I figured it out after looking over my code about a thousand times, I forgot the ~ in front of my link for font-awesome and bootstrap. It's working now, Thanks for your help